# ¿Cuál es la función equivalente de SQL Server DATEFROMPARTS() en PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, postgresql-12

Actualmente me encuentro trabajando con PostgreSQL, entonces quisiera saber si hay una función donde pueda crear fechas parecidas a la función de `DATEFROMPARTS()` .

```
SELECT 
DATEFROMPARTS(2020,12,31) a_date;
```

**Su salida es:**

```
a_date
----------
2020-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

`MAKE_DATE`: [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-datetime.html#:~:text=make_date(year%20int%2C%20month%20int%2C%20day%20int)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-datetime.html#:%7E:text=make_date(year%20int%2C%20month%20int%2C%20day%20int))

```sql
SELECT MAKE_DATE(2020,12,31) a_date;

-- output:
-- --------------
-- | 2020-12-31 |
-- --------------
```

Comment: Gracias,  tengo una columna de tipo date, entonces debido a su formato no puedo utilizar MAKE_DATE() porque acepta valores de enteros, lo que hizo fue hacer un: SELECT  EXTRACT (YEAR FROM 'name_column') AS name_other, asi mismo para month y day. luego cambiar el tipo de dato de numeric a int y aplicar el MAKE_DATE(). Complejo pero no encontre otra foroma